# BuildError when trying to use Flask fields.Url

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask and SqlAlchemy to build an API, but having a problem with `fields.Url()`, which I cannot figure out. I am getting the following error:

```
BuildError: ('storagenode_ep', MultiDict([('_sa_instance_state', <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x4a76ad0>), ('id', 7), ('hostname', u'testNode1')]), None)
```

It works fine if I just return the id instead of trying to use `field.Url()`.
The following simplified class demonstrates the issue:

```
storagenode_fields = {
    'hostname': fields.String,
    'uri': fields.Url('storagenode_ep')
    # 'id': fields.String
}

class StorageNodeAPI(Resource):
    @marshal_with(storagenode_fields)
    def get(self, storagenode_id):
        return StorageNode.query.filter_by(id=storagenode_id).first()

api.add_resource(StorageNodeAPI, '/api/storagenodes/<string:storagenode_id>', endpoint='storagenode_ep')
```

I have [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261833/what-is-an-endpoint-in-flask) to better understand how endpoints, but I am still stuck.

The `StorageNode class` is defined as follows:

```
class StorageNode(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'storagenode'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    hostname = Column(String(150), unique=True)
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign 'storagenode_ep' before returning it

Solved similar problem with help from [How to add fields url for nested output fields in flask restful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453636/how-to-add-fields-url-for-nested-output-fields-in-flask-restful)

But if you are using Blueprints, add "`.`" to the `fields.Url` eg 
`'uri': fields.Url('.storagenode_ep')`

ref https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/266#issuecomment-46678118